# How to create a counter that increments by 1 every 1-8 seconds(random)

Tags: javascript, random, setinterval, clearinterval

So I think I'm close, but what I've written begins to increment by larger values, and at an increasing speed the longer it runs. I assume this is an issue with the interval not being properly cleared. Please assist in anyway possible.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            function setTimer(){
                var timer = (((Math.floor(Math.random() * 6))+1)*1000);
                clearInterval(interval);
                var interval = setInterval(updateCounter, timer);
            }

            function updateCounter(){
                var counter = document.getElementById("counter");                    
                var count = parseInt(counter.innerHTML);
                count++;
                counter.innerHTML = count;
                setTimer();
            }

        </script>
    </head> 

    <body style="margin:5%;" onload="setTimer()">
        <div id="counter">1</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, `interval` exitsts scope as soon as you go out of `setTimer`, so you are clearing nothing.

Comment: Have you thought of using `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`?

Comment: When you try to clear it, `interval` doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Your `interval` variable needs to be declared outside of the function of you want it to persist between calls to `setTimer()`.

Comment: `var interval` is local in scope, define it outside of the function or consider using `setTimeout`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `interval` variable is a local variable to `setTimer`. `clearInterval(interval);` won't work, because you are passing `undefined` (the value of `interval`). It won't throw an error though because of **variable hoisting** but the value you pass to `clearInterval` is `undefined` for sure.

**Fix #1:**

Declare `interval` outside `setTimer`:

```
var interval;
function setTimer(){
    var timer = (((Math.floor(Math.random() * 6))+1)*1000);
    clearInterval(interval);
    interval = setInterval(updateCounter, timer);            // no redeclaring here
}
```

**Fix #2:**

Since you are clearing intervals right before setting them again, you could use `setTimeout` as it perfectly fit your needs:

```
function setTimer() {
    var timer = (((Math.floor(Math.random() * 6))+1)*1000);
    setTimeout(updateCounter, timer);                        // no clearing is needed this time
}
```

**Note:**

Your `timer` variable will be between 1-6 seconds. You said you wanted it to be 1-8, so use:

```
var timer = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 8) + 1) * 1000;
```

Comment: I'd add that using `setTimeout` is a much better choice here.

Comment: @ChrisG That was my initial thoguht as well. But decided to post the problem first. I'm editing the answer now.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir The count is not updating in your second solution it's just called one time.

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze `setTimer` is called at the bottom of `updateCounter` so a loop is established.

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze BTW, you may want to change your name. Haven't you heard Kevin Spacey's lattest news.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir oh yeah I missed that. No need to call it then

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze ...Perhaps verbalKintIsKeyserSöze is a better replacement.

Comment: Thank you! simple as that... I'll make the switch to setTimeout - just more familiar with setInterval so it was my first thought.. Appreciate the help/fast replies everyone!

Comment: @TCooper You're welcome! Use `setInterval` when the time interval is fixed. Use `setTimeout` otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the `updateCounter` method should know it is called from a timer and be responsible for calling `setTimer()`. What if you want to call the method to update the counter from somewhere else that is not using a timer. Managing the call to `updateCounter` should be done by the controlling code IMHO.
Also, using `setTimeOut()` might be better here as you then don't have to manage the intervals.

```js
function setTimer() {
  var timer = (((Math.floor(Math.random() * 6)) + 1) * 1000);
  setTimeout(function() {
    updateCounter();
    setTimer();
  }, timer)
}

function updateCounter() {
  var counter = document.getElementById("counter");
  var count = parseInt(counter.innerHTML);
  count++;
  counter.innerHTML = count;
}
```

```html
<body style="margin:5%;" onload="setTimer()">
  <div id="counter">1</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest moving `setTimer()` outside of `updateCounter()` otherwise you will be creating new intervals everytime you call `updateCounter()`. Try

```
    function setTimer(){
        var timer = (((Math.floor(Math.random() * 6))+1)*1000);
        var interval = setInterval(updateCounter, timer);
    }

    function updateCounter(){
        var counter = document.getElementById("counter");                    
        var count = parseInt(counter.innerHTML);
        count++;
        counter.innerHTML = count;
    }

    setTimer();
```

EDIT: removed `clearInterval`